# Cask 'thorn-writing' definition is invalid error which I didn't installed

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

when I try

```
$ brew search SOME_NAME
```

homebrew returns

```
$ brew search chrome
Error: Cask 'thorn-writing' definition is invalid: invalid 'depends_on macos' value: unknown or unsupported macOS version: :mavericks
```

but I did not have thorn-writing installed, means

```
brew list --cask
```

does not show the name "thron-writing".
tried removing mavericks reference like https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/84118,
but the error keeps occuring. any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/84541
found that thorn-writing Formulae is deleted from original repository,looks like it is not applied to my local repository?
tried
$ brew update 
or 
$ brew tap --full
but with no success.

Comment: removing depends_on line from 
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks/thorn-writing.rb
seems work (brew search command returns no error), but is it proper way to fix the issue?